# simple jQuery autocomplete example not working in ASP.NET Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

This thread is related to my previous thread ([Using a forced suggestion mechanism using JavaScript and jQuery (ASP.NET MVC project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844987/using-a-forced-suggestion-mechanism-using-javascript-and-jquery-asp-net-mvc-pro)). But the problem I am experiencing is too big to place it in there.

I am trying to gte the simple jQuery autocomplete example (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to work in my ASP.NET NVC 4 webapp. I tried this:

```
@model PoliticiOnline.DTO.Question

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Stel een vraag!";
}

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Questions.css" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


    <script>
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
            ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<h2>Stel een vraag!</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Vraag</legend>

        <div class="general-question">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GeneralQuestion, "Algemene Vraag")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GeneralQuestion, new{@class = "general-question-edit"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GeneralQuestion)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="geadresseerde-politici">
            @Html.Label("Politicus")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PoliticianId, (SelectList)ViewBag.PolIds)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Explanation, "Extra Uitleg")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Explanation, new{@class = "explanation-textarea-edit"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Explanation)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Indienen!" />
        </p>

        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags"/>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

It's just the autocompleting that is not working (I'm not yet trying to send it with the form, I just want the autocomplete to work).

When I start typing in the inputfield nothing happens, but it shoudl actually give suggestions.

Comment: What error are you getting on your browser console window? preferably when u type in

Comment: Hmm I get the following on page load: "Uncaught ReferenceError: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined "

Comment: You forgot to load jquery library or there is an error from the load source!

Comment: I thought this was enough: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") What do I need to do? The jQuery bundle isn't corruptes because it works on another page (on which I also only do @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am almost certain the error :

**`"Uncaught ReferenceError: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`**

means that jquery is not being loaded onto your page.

**Load jquery from CDN or something like this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Try using:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () { }
```

Comment: If I put that line in <head> it doesn't solve it :( Weird thing is that I use jQuery on another page and it fully works. And I just do the @Render.Scripts... I am puzzled

Comment: Oh my god I fixed the jQuery error!! I made some kind of type and said @Render.Scripts(~/bundles/jqueryval) which should just be jquery! Only error left is: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'

Comment: Okay , then you must load the `jquery UI` library!
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: Every js file is loaded but I still get the "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete' " error

Comment: Load all files after loading jquery file?

Comment: yes This is the loading part: (I use the jQuery ui file that is in my project by default): `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>`

Comment: Try loading this jquery UI file : `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thats probably it, try using Firebug on FF, its a really handy tool for debugging

Comment: I have used it in the past but is it better than Chrome console?

Comment: Much better , we would have solved this way before i you had used Firebug , better late than never :)

Comment: FB tells me this: TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
 

source: availableTags

Comment: I don't get errors now and everything seems to be included (although it's mixed local and code.jquery.com) but I still don't get the damn autocomplete list under the input :(

Comment: Load this : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> `

Comment: No errors, no working autocomplete :/ It seems like the jQuery files get loaded, but somehow don't get used (right)